# Python 3 sched module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script that will run code at the top of every minute.  I'm looking into the sched module and I've encountered some strange problems.

The first problem is that importing sched runs my script twice.

```
import sched
print('hello')
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hello
```

Also this code which comes straight from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html):

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
```

produces this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'sched' has no attribute 'scheduler'
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `sched.py` by any chance. This works on both python2 and python3.

Comment: Tried both of your examples, and they worked fine on my end. Might want to make sure your environment is setup correctly.

Comment: Yes, I had named the file sched.py.  It appears i was importing the file within itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment - your file is named `sched.py`, therefore, it was importing itself, of which doesn't have the attribute `scheduler`.